# Autocomplete Extender ajax on pressing enter key

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit, autocompleteextender

I have created Ajax autocomplete extender on my web page that retrieves the values from the database.
When I select one of the options from the autocomplete dropdown list I get the desired result.
The problem is:

When the user types entire word by himself (or if the word is pasted) and when he does not select one of the options from the dropdownlist and presses enter, result is blank.
How do I solve this problem?

My code for autocomplete extender is:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenID" runat="server" />
            <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
            <asp:TextBox ID="SearchRetailer" runat="server" Style="background-image: url(Search-icon.png ); border: 1px groove black; background-position: right; background-repeat: no-repeat; float: right; width: 20%;" />
            <asp:AutoCompleteExtender
                ID="AutoCompleteExtender1"
                TargetControlID="tgt1"
                runat="server" MinimumPrefixLength="2" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList" UseContextKey="True" OnClientItemSelected="GetCode" EnableCaching="true" />
```

The javascript function is:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function GetCode(source, eventArgs) {
        var hfield = $get('<%=this.HiddenID.ClientID%>');
        hfield.value = eventArgs.get_value();
        window.open("newPage.aspx?Paramter1=" + hfield.value + "", "_self", false);
    }

</script>
```

And my webservice code is:

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethodAttribute(), System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethodAttribute()]
public static string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count, string contextKey)
{

    SqlConnection sqlconn = "my connection string"

    string sql = "select abc from aaa where abc like '" + prefixText + "%'";
    SqlDataAdapter cmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, sqlconn);
    DataTable dt0r = new DataTable();
    cmd1.Fill(dt0r);
    int i = 0;
    string[] rList = new string[dt0r.Rows.Count];        
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt0r.Rows)
    {
        rList.SetValue(dr["abc"].ToString(), i);

        i++;
    }
    return rList;

}
```

Comment: I got the answer.I added FirstRowSelected="true" in the properties of the autocomplete extender and the functionality is now working!!

Comment: you should add this as an answer and mark it as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work.

I added FirstRowSelected="true" in the properties of the autocomplete extender and the functionality is now working!!